# Not able to connect socket in react native

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I'm trying to connect socket in react native. I am able to connect same socket in html file.

Server Code :

```
const express = require("express")
    , app = express()
    , http = require("http").createServer(app)
    , fs = require("fs")
    , io = require("socket.io")(http);


app.use(express.static("public"));

http.listen("8080", () => {
    console.log("Server Started");
});

function socketIdsInRoom(name) {
    var socketIds = io.nsps['/'].adapter.rooms[name];
    if (socketIds) {
        var collection = [];
        for (var key in socketIds) {
            collection.push(key);
        }
        return collection;
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    console.log('connection');

    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        console.log('disconnect');
    });
});
```

React Native Code:

```
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:8080', { transports: ['websocket'] });

//const socket = io("http://127.0.0.1:8080"); /* I've also tried this */
socket.on('connect', function (data) {
    console.log('connect');
});
```

I'm using **socket.io-client** for socket connections in react native

Comment: any console log errors?

Comment: @Metalik None. I've checked it with `react-native log-android`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is related to `127.0.0.1` ip. Android can't connect to 127.0.0.1 ip because it is internal loop back IP.

You should replace `127.0.0.1` with your server Ip ether external or internal IP.

Comment: It worked after changing the ip. Thanks for the response.